# Mercurial : See more changesets at once

Tags: netbeans, mercurial, tortoisehg

I do use Netbeans and TortoiseHG to manage and view Mercurial changesets but my problem is that I want to see differences for a range of changeset.

Real case: Gil is working on a feature in his own repo and he adds more changes incrementally.
His changesets are: 47(message: initial tests), 48, 49 (message: fixed bug added in 47), 50 (message: feature ready).

[Changeset 46 was made by me (Alex) so I know the code until 46 inclusive]

If I do review each commit I might spend time on bugs he already fixed down the road (ex: I see a bug in 47 but he fixed it in 49).

I want to avoid reviewing each commit and I want to be able to review whole 47-50 range at once - as a single change set.

Is there any tool, option, tweak to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseHg can launch a visual diff of two revisions or it can output a diff file for them.

The instructions for Windows are as follows:

1. Click on one revision
2. Ctrl-click the other revision
3. Right click on either of them
4. **Visual Diff...** will launch your configured visual difference tool and **Export Diff...** will create a patch file for you to review.

This is probably available for other OSs that TortoiseHg supports but the clicks may be different.

This launches KDiff3 on my system which gives a tree containing all the changed files.  Double-clicking on one of the files show the changes in another pane.

Comment: Thanks...is the closest tool to what I need